# Two Column Layout with centered and left aligned content

Tags: css, grid

I am looking to create a two column list. Where the content width is based off of the largest element and then left aligned and centered.
[image]

It would look something like that.
The code is similar to this

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>United States</label>
  </div>
    <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
      <label>Canada</label>
  </div> 
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Brazil</label>
  </div>
    <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
      <label>Argentina</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Peru</label>
  </div> 
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
  <label>Ivory Coast</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Really Long Content</label>
  </div>
    <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
      <label>Guatamala</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `width:max-content` and `margin:auto` on:

- a `grid`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
  gap: 0 1em;
}

.radio {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>United States</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Canada</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Brazil</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Argentina</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Peru</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Ivory Coast</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Really Long Content</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Guatamala</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

- or a css column via `column-count:2;`

```css
.grid {column-count:2;
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 1em; /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 1em;
  width:max-content;
  margin:auto;
  border:solid;
}

.radio {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>United States</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Canada</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Brazil</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Argentina</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Peru</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Ivory Coast</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Really Long Content</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio">
    <label>Guatamala</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

*added a 1em gap in between columns for the demos.*